# Leaflet: Map Click Event doesn't work when clicked on an overlay geojson layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet in one of my projects and I'm facing an issue, which is explained below:

I've implemented a click event on the map using

```
map.on('click', function(e) {        
    console.log(e)       
});
```

and everything is working fine.

I've also added a geojson layer on map. So, the problem is when I click on the overlay geojson layer (which is a polygon layer actually), the map click event not fired. Hence, my question is what should I do so that map click event also work when I click on an overlay layer on map?

Comment: Why are you not binding to the overlay layer?Do you want to capture clicks on the map or on the specific features?

Comment: The overlay layer is it's own object, separate from the map object.  If you're going to bind an event to the map object, it won't automatically transfer to the overlay.  You need to bind the event to the overlay instead of/in addition to the map object, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

As it's being said in the comments the `click` event is binded to the map or to the overlay layers but it's not bubbled from one to another. You must attach it to the desired object.

You can bind the click to the whole overlay as it inherits from [L.Evented](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#evented) or to individual features.

To bind it to individual features check the [onEachFeature section of the tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

```
function onEnachFeature(feature, layer) {
    console.log(feature.properties);
}
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve the the [bindPopup](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layer-bindpopup) and the [bindTooltip](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layer-bindtooltip) will be useful.

Also, take into account that as the [doc explains](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#featuregroup)

> Events are propagated to the FeatureGroup, so if the group has an
>   event handler, it will handle events from any of the layers. This
>   includes mouse events and custom events.

So you can choose to bind to each feature or to the layer with similar effects depending on your use case.